# How to check sequelize count and return Boolean value if count > 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Nodejs and I have a query to get count. I want to check if `count > 0` to return true, else - false.
But I can't handle it using nodejs.
Here's my code:

```js
const uidIsConnection = (model, entityId, uid) =>
  models[model].count({
   where: { entityId, profileId: uid }
  });

var data = uidIsConnection('ProfileData', user.id, id);
//I want this variable data to have the value of true or false
```

Now, `data` returns promise:

```js
Promise {
  _bitField: 2097152,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _boundTo: profiledata }
```

How to return boolean value depending on `count > 0`, not promise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequelize `count` returns a Promise, which is what your `data` is resolving to. To get the actual count of the function you should do:

```
const uidIsConnection = (model, entityId, uid) =>
        models[model].count({
            where: { entityId, profileId: uid }
        });

uidIsConnection('ProfileData', user.id, id).then(count => {
    console.log('boolean version of count', !!count);
});
```

In the future you could use `asyc` `await` to resolve this synchronously, but the feature is not [widely supported yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).